# Como é possível evitar que o SOpt falhe como vêm falhando a versão americana do site?

Tags: debate

Não me entendam mal, a versão original do site tem várias respostas interessantes e muitas vezes encontro uma solução exata para o meu problema sem nem mesmo perguntar nada.

Nesse sentido o site é bom.

Por outro lado, ao contrário do senso de colaboração e real interesse de se responder às perguntas - como é visto aqui no SOpt - a grande maioria dos usuários "veteranos" vão simplesmente tentar arranjar um jeito de fazerem trancar tua pergunta, de dar downvote e má resposta.

É sério. Foi por isso que parei de postar lá (daí que fui ver que minha conta está trancada, por causa de downvotes provavelmente).

Daí depois de quase 1 ano voltei para fazer uma pergunta no Programmers SE (que assim como o SO e o SO meta, sofre dos mesmos problemas), e veja o que aconteceu: 
[Why the most popular general purpose languages have adopted more complex syntax?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/327710/why-the-most-popular-general-purpose-languages-have-adopted-more-complex-syntax)

Por enquanto 2 downvotes, e comentários afirmando que a minha questão é um duplicate dessa [Does syntax really matter in a programming language? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30135/does-syntax-really-matter-in-a-programming-language)

Sério? É só ler o títula da questão e já dá para ver que são duas coisas bem distintas sendo perguntadas. 
Daí fui dar uma pesquisada para ver se era só eu que estava fazendo algo errado, porque afinal, eu já participei - inclusive moderei - fóruns na internet, e dos grandes. O básico que tirei disso é que se você quer ser levado à sério você tem que ler as regras. Mas no SO não adianta, você lê, relê, daí quando você posta a questão principal é como vão fazer tua questão sair do ar, e não como respondê-la.

Daí como ia dizendo, pesquisei e vi que não sou o único. Iniciantes geral são rechaçados sem só, enquanto perguntas estúpidas como "Será que a sintaxe das linguagens realmente importa?", trancada como off topic, chove de upvote.

Ah sinceramente né, uma vergonha. Espero que o SOpt não tome o mesmo rumo pois pelo que vejo aqui realmente existe um senso de cooperação, apesar de não ter tantos experts quanto lá.

---

PS: Me desculpe o tom um pouco inflamado, mas é que acabei de fazer esse post lá e não adianta. Não vou tentar mais, porque não importa o tempo que passa, volto lá é sempre a mesma coisa, enxurrada de críticas, alguns quase que insultam a gente.

Tentei levar a sério, mas não dá.

Answer (score 11):

*"a grande maioria dos usuários "veteranos" vão simplesmente tentar arranjar um jeito de fazerem trancar tua pergunta"* - isto não é verdade aqui (nem pela minha experiência no SOen).

O que acontece, e isso pode ser confundido, é que os utilizadores veteranos sabem que tipo de informação uma pergunta precisa de ter para ser respondida e conseguem ver padrões que os fazem agir com mais confiança que utilizadores não vetereanos. Isso pode ser confundido com "não querer ajudar", mas não é isso de todo.

Vou dar-te uma ideia de [como eu penso](https://www.mindmup.com/#m:a1760594703dc801341c5535caf02f8363) quando vejo uma pergunta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aspetos que não referi e que influenciam são factores como:

- o utilizador já tentou resolver o problema?
- o utilizador mostra conhecer a linguagem e compreender o problema?
- o utilizador participa ativamente nos esclarecimentos necessários

etc... tudo isto influência como a pergunta é tratada.

Comment: Fantástico esse fluxograma! Deveria fazer parte da central de ajuda, isso facilitaria muito usuario que está chegando agora a compreender melhor porque sua pergunta foi fechada, e até nós, editores dessa fila, a ter um pouco mais de discernimento em comum na hora de analisar os fechamentos! :)

Comment: @diegofm estava falando isso pro Sergio no chat dos moderadores. Ajudaria muita gente. Mas vamos dar um jeito de aproveitar isso de alguma forma.

Comment: Muito bom o fluxograma Sergio =D Vc poderia me dizer qual programa usou para criar ele?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho esse fiz com o [mindmup](https://www.mindmup.com/#m:a1760594703dc801341c5535caf02f8363), e outro que conheço é o https://www.draw.io/. Provavelmente há mais.

Answer (score 9):

Eu poderia responder ponto a ponto do que colocou na pergunta. Mas não vai ajudar muito, e falar de outro site da rede não é o objetivo aqui. Então focarei no que importa, e isso é simples.

Use o site que está confortável que será mais proveitoso e divertido. Você está se sentindo bem aqui, aproveite o máximo e colabore para que o site sempre seja o que deseja.

Claro que pode insistir em usar um site que não está te agradando, mas isso requer esforço, adaptação e ceder um pouco. Uma comunidade é o que é, e a melhor forma é se adaptar a ela para alcançar seus objetivos. Não estou dizendo que não possa tentar mudar alguma coisa, mas teria que fazer lá, e teria que ser muito persistente e persuasivo. Mesmo assim não há garantias. Então o meu conselho pessoal - e você pode fazer o que quiser, claro - é que concentre suas forças aqui.

Entendo sua frustração, mas outras pessoas, de acordo com a experiência e convicções delas, podem estar frustradas com sua pergunta. Concorda que elas são tão humanas quanto você? Aí entra em uma situação em que todo mundo perde. Adoraria que fosse diferente, mas eu só consigo ver um jeito de uma situação assim se resolver: modificar a pergunta (o que pode ser bem difícil). Inflamar não costuma dar certo. Aí a situação fica perdida de vez e a frustração só aumenta.

Eu não vou falar especificamente sobre a pergunta postada lá porque o que foi perguntado aqui não é sobre ela - acho que que nem caberia discutir aqui - e minha resposta sairia do escopo, mas eu estou com dificuldade para sugerir para postá-la aqui para tentar uma resposta, porque eu acho que ela teria o mesmo destino e você ficaria bravo com todo mundo aqui também. A pergunta talvez não seja tão boa quanto imagina que seja.