# Em comparação ao SOen, a qualidade do SOpt vai bem, obrigado!

Tags: debate, qualidade

Gostaria de abrir este debate para que possamos não fazer uma comparação direta, mas para que tenhamos alguma noção da qualidade das duas versões do SO.

Em termos de volume de usuários, o SOen é aproximadamente 100x maior que o SOpt, mas creio que mesmo com um tamanho considerável, a qualidade não deveria ser deixada pra baixo.

Uso SOen para muitas pesquisas e noto que lá muitas perguntas possuem muitas respostas que no SOpt seriam fechadas ou negativadas, mas ao contrário, lá elas muitas vezes (talvez, a maioria das vezes) não são fechadas ou negativadas e pelo contrário, algumas recebem até mais votos positivos do que muitas boas respostas no SOpt.

Geralmente são respostas baseadas em links ou com uma qualidade muito baixa, e pior, já vi casos em que a resposta nem atendia à pergunta, e mesmo assim recebem até alguns up votes.

Isso me levou a pensar que a qualidade do SOpt é superior (e muito) em relação ao SOen em termos de moderação (talvez até em relação a usuários). Imagino que as regras dos dois sites sejam a mesma (ou não?).

Será porque no SOen a quantidade de usuários e tão grande (cerca de 8 milhões de usuários) que não se consegue moderar de forma eficiente e qualquer usuário vota em qualquer coisa?

Como se pode avaliar a qualidade do SOpt em relação ao SOen nesse contexto?

### Edit

Um exemplo de resposta baseada em link que obteve 15 up votes (poucas vezes uma boa resposta no SOpt consegue essa quantidade de votos, mesmo mais antigas):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que o usuário nem dá precisão na resposta: "This should help" ("*isto poderia ajudar*", bem diferente de "*isto irá lhe ajudar*").

Link da resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700697/1377664

Comment: As regras são semelhantes, mas no princípio do SOpt os fundadores meio que estabeleceram que muitos dos vícios do SOen não seriam herdados. A comunidade estava sendo formada, nova, então eles poderiam dar um melhor direcionamento. No SOen não sabe sabia ao certo como lidar com isso, foi um crescimento cheio de falhas por a comunidade ainda estar se descobrindo enquanto se desenrolava

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Então essa deve ser a explicação. O SOpt já pegou o bonde andando.

Comment: Eu já li nos primeiros posts aqui do meta, vou procurar para dar maior profundidade ao debate

Comment: Acho que a questão levantada é bem interessante, eu próprio já me tinha deparado com essa discrepância. Em relação à resposta do SOen acho incrível que tenha 15 upvotes sendo bem fraca como é.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5240/64969

Comment: @Isac Eu também há muito vinha notado isso. Já até dei gargalhadas em algumas situações. Uma resposta como essa seria rechaçada de pronto no SOpt.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/64969

Comment: Você só mostrou a data de edição, mas essa resposta tem 7 anos. Mais ou menos 2 votos por ano. E o SOen daquele tempo não era o que é hoje.

Comment: @bfavaretto Mostrei o que a página me mostrava. Eu deveria mostrar algo mais?

Comment: @bfavaretto Mas isso é o de menos. Mostra que a edição é relativamente recente, apenas 1 ano.

Comment: @bfavaretto O original da resposta (sem a edição) seria diferente e melhor? Ou o cara foi piorando a resposta?

Comment: Olhando para o histórico de edições da resposta, vemos que ela sofreu do mal que aqui é advocado contra escrever esse tipo de respostas, que é a possibilidade do link ser removido/alterado

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que, considerando o volume de conteúdo do SOen, é meio que normal coisas assim ficarem pra trás, ainda mais se forem antigas. No começo, valia tudo, e essa resposta pode ter acumulado alguns votos. Nos anos seguintes continuou recebendo alguns acessos pelo google e ganhou mais alguns votos. Não é difícil chegar a 15. Eu tenho respostas bestas lá com alta pontuação ([exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757261)).

Comment: `answered Apr 18 '11 at 9:08` é antiga demais essa resposta, nao creio que uma resposta dessas la atualmente consiga um saldo desses, não sem um sinal de menos na frente. Ao menos nas tags que visito por lá, o povo é bem exigente.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pois é... acho que isso era antigamente mesmo.

Comment: Apenas para por lenha na fogueira, discordamos sobre a objetividade da qualidade desta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277762/64969; pretendo elaborar uma resposta a esse tópico aberto, mas enquanto não paro para escrever, deposito mais esse ponto de informação aqui

Comment: Concordo com você, mas também acho que a galera pega bastante pesado aqui, digo os usuários.. tem muito downvote de graça e poucos upvotes pra quem realmente merece.. o nível de crítica é muito grande, já recebi comentários em perguntas/respostas minhas porque a pessoa sequer se deu ao trabalho de ler e entender meu questionamento.. :)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, parece que os comentários foram excluídos :P

Comment: Além de regras diferentes é necessário considerar o tamanho da fila de moderacao como bem apotado pelo @bfavaretto. Como alguém que participa de ambas as comunidades eu posso dizer que eventualmente boa parte dos problemas são arrumados... Só que o tempo de reação médio é de semana / meses e não de horas.

Comment: Em média eu acho que ambas as comunidades tem vantagens e desvantagens. Se tenho uma dúvida muito específica sobre alguma técnologia nova o SOen geralmente me dá resultados melhores. se busco uma resposta de qualidade para um problema não trivial geralmente posto no SOpt, temos uma meia dúzia de pessoas por aqui que sempre dão respostas fenomenais.

Comment: Detalhe: lembro de uma discussão com o Gabe e alguns mods e usuários ativos na época do Beta. O consenso na mesa era que começar no SOen era bem chato, que o pessoal moderava com punhos de ferro por lá e nós seriamos mais brandos. A atitude do pessoal envolvido no começo era a de criar uma "sociedade discreta do bem". É engraçado ler agora sobre como os moderadores do SOen não são duros o suficiente e como eles devem seguir a cultura daqui. As coisas mudam... :D

Comment: Acho que lá o pessoal é mais rigoroso com perguntas do que com respostas: se vc fizer uma pergunta, digamos, "razoável", em poucos minutos já ganha alguns _downvotes_. Enquanto que no SOpt, se brincar, ganha até _upvotes_ a mesma pergunta. Mas acho isso tudo muito relativo. Como o SOen é um site de alcance mais Global, por assim dizer, são várias culturas, várias "cabeças", enquanto que no SOpt isso se torna mais compacto.